# PerformSegueWithIdentifier blowing up

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a weird situation happening. Here is a brief description of my layout:

Sign-in View controller -> Main Table View Controller (has logoff button) -> Second Table View Controller (has logoff button) -> Help Menu.

So when the user gets to the help menu and clicks the logoff button it dumps them back to the second view controller which at that point it blows up saying:

`Thread 1: Exception: "Receiver (<xxx.SecondViewController: 0x7fa72b9cc040>) has no segue with identifier 'SignupViewController'"`

The code for the logoff button is as follows:

```
@IBAction func btnLogoutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignupViewController", sender: self)
    }
```

Within the SecondViewController I also have a logoff button which has the exact same code as the  help view controller.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you must show a pic of storyBoard. and identify the segues. is unclear where the segue are connected but your error show that you menu VC does not have a segue to SingnupViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a segue in your storyboard for SecondViewController to SignupViewController and set that segue identifier to "SignupViewController". Then it will work.

I guess now the segue is available only from Main Table View Controller to SignupViewController with identifier "SignupViewController", if so it will work only from Main Table View Controller.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your second comment, I did try adding a segue from the SecondViewController to Signup and it still blewup.

Comment: I meant you have segue only from Main Tableviewcontroller to SignupViewController and not from SecondViewController to Signup. However, now you have added the segue from SecondViewController to Signup.  Did you set the segue identifier as "SignupViewController"?  If you can provide the screenshot of storyboard it would be good to understand.

Comment: Got it Nandish, thanks for the help, I was missing the identifier.